# How can I setting address of .m2 repository folder for maven project?

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat

I install my new Window OS and run my old maven project on Tomcat Server. Then I get this message, "DUY" is my old user. I don't know how to setting my project to read .m2 folder of new user. I tried to clean project, maven clean, maven install, but it's not working

[image]

UPDATE:
The solution is Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> User Settings and set User Settings field point to setting.xml file in maven home folder

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to:

Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> User Settings

There you will see a field for you to configure your local repository a.k.a. `m2` folder.

EDIT:

In that same page, check where it is pointing to the `settings.xml` file, open it and then check to where that file is pointing to your local repository.

Comment: I tried your solution but my local repository already been configured in my new user

Comment: Then, in that same page, check where it is pointing to the `settings.xml` file, open it and then check to where that file is pointing to your local repository. I've added this to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in User Settings field, I pointing to settings.xml file in my maven home folder and it's worked